What can be determined from a knob-and-tube inspection without opening walls?
We purchased a house (built in 1920) with some knob and tube wiring and are closing next week. Home has 3 bedrooms upstairs and 1 in basement and 2.5 baths. Around 1400 ft^2 plus finished basement. We contacted an electrician in our area whose bread and butter is knob and tube. We've agreed to an inspection of sorts. He is planning to send two people to our house and will charge $140/hr (should take about two hours he said) to inspect the house and determine the extent of changes needed on the K&T end and if there are other wiring issues, etc. that we should be aware of. He estimated $20-25k for a full rewire and service upgrade and half of that if its 50% K&T.
I'm wondering a few things.
Can anybody comment on what exactly can be determined by an electrician without damaging any of the walls? I know that in order to complete the work, they will ultimately need to penetrate the walls. He indicated maybe 4-5 small holes to do the ultimate work (there is a crawl space upstairs so he said that the upstairs should be less of an issue). I'm just wondering how reliable an estimate would be from him after this inspection if everything is hidden behind the walls? Want to really just understand what sort of questions we should ask while they're here to better understand what is going on.
I know it is difficult to understand the extent of K&T just by seeing the fixtures by the panel and the actual panel. It seems like the service is 150 AMPS which should be enough for our needs I'm guessing if we don't have any insane needs (won't be running space heaters or window units). There are 30 switches on the panel but only 20 or so are like installed. Only a few are labeled. Just trying to understand what might put us at ease that an entire rewire is unlikely?
Our main needs at this point are insurance and peace of mind. We were rejected outright by quite a few insurance companies and would prefer to get this fixed if it would make our lives easier and give us comfort.

Call several other electricians to get quotes. You'll get different prices and different scopes of work from each of them, but it'll give you an idea of what's really needed (other than "the K&T needs to go!").

It kind of feels like nonsense to me, a way to make you feel like you're getting something real, but then "locking you in" to them as a vendor due to the fallacy of sunk costs.  Shrewd marketing.

Just to add to the answers… there’s a lot of evil/stupid (pick one or both) modifications that can have happened in the intervening century. Some of these will be well hidden; others not so much. If it was my house, I’d plan for a complete top to bottom rewire and budget accordingly.

Focusing on the one question I see: There are usually more signs of knob and tube wiring which are easily accessible without going in the walls, so you can tell a fair bit without opening up the walls. Ultimately to really see what is going on you will need to at least make some holes. In some cases a small camera can be threaded in to the wall to find out more information starting from a box or a tiny hole.

This admittedly is somewhat my opinion.  My thought would be the K&T has to go, so why inspect?
I would get multiple estimates based on upgrading all the electric to current code.  Make a decision from there.  Inspecting and having the Electrician say that some K&T is ok and leave it only to have the insurance companies reject you is useless.

Hello! This is a valid train of thought. The company we contacted first basically indicated they would not be able to quickly provide a quote as it is more involved to fully assess what is there... as a result, he charges $140/hr for a team of 2 to come out and look through everything in detail. That is credited toward any future work. He gave me some rough numbers to do partial or complete rewire but we really wouldn't know where we land until somebody looks more extensively.
